# How to add a gui list from an array?

Tags: java

This is the code I have already. For now I want to be able to make my own string array and then make it as a list in my gui. I tried a couple just adding it to the panel and that didnt work. Any ideas how I would go about doing this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.*;

public class plannerGUI {

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p2;
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton b1;
    private JLabel label;
    public plannerGUI() {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {
        f = new JFrame("Planner");

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new JPanel();
        p2 = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Add Date");
        label = new JLabel("Upcoming Events");


        p2.add(label);
        p.add(b1);


        f.add(p2);
        f.add(p,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new plannerGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Actionlistener for JButton (b1) and implement there something from code (handling).

```
b1.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
    //.. to do something;
});
```